# Passing a vector object to a function and returning

Tags: c++, function, object, vector, return

I have a program where I am creating n objects for a structure using a vector. I want to pass this vector to function get_stud_data where I input the names of student. I want and return all vector objects to main function

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "stdio.h"

using namespace std;

struct students
{
string name; // I am not sure
int roll_no;
};

vector<p>& get_stud_data(vector<students> & p, int n)
{
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
cout<<"Enter Name of " <<i+1<<"th student\n";
cin>> p[i].name;
}
return p;
}

int main()
{

int n;
cout<<" Enter the number of students: ";
cin>> n;

vector<students> p(n); // creating n objects for struct students

  // Want to retrieve the objects here.
    p=get_stud_data()
    return 0;

    }
```

Comment: You are passing vector as reference so you will get updated vector. You don't need to return vector. Just use updated vector which is passed as reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to. You pass in your vector as a **reference** so your function can change it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct student
{
  string name;
  int roll_no;
};

void get_student_data(vector<student>& students)
{
  for(int i = 0; i < students.size() ; i++ )
  {
    cout << "Enter Name of " << i+1 << "th student\n";
    cin >> students[i].name;
  }
}

int main()
{
  int n;

  cout << " Enter the number of students: ";
  cin >> n;

  vector<student> students(n); 

  get_student_data(students);

  // cout some students here to see it worked

  return 0;
}
```

If you really want to return a vector, you can. It's just pointless in this exercise because then you have two:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct student
{
  string name;
  int roll_no;
};

vector<student> get_student_data(vector<student>& students)
{
  for(int i = 0; i < students.size() ; i++ )
  {
    cout << "Enter Name of " << i+1 << "th student\n";
    cin >> students[i].name;
  }
  return students;
}

int main()
{
  int n;

  cout << " Enter the number of students: ";
  cin >> n;

  vector<student> students(n); 

  vector<student> copy = get_student_data(students);

  // now you have the same data copied into "copy" and "students"
  // cout some students here to see it worked

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I want to return the vector back to main function as I need to do further process. How to return the vector of objects p and catch it in the main function

Comment: @Step You don't *need* to return it, you still *have it*. It's not gone. The instance with the name of `students`  does still exist and was changed by your function.

Comment: ok col but is it possible to return it. I want to know how vector objects could be returned.

Comment: great thanks nvoigt I got the concept Indeed I shall use the first program

Answer (score 0):

If what you really want to do is to read a vector of n students and return it to the caller, you can just do:

```
vector<student> get_student_data(int n)
{
  vector<student> v(n);
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
    cout << "Enter Name of " << (i+1) <<"th student\n";
    cin >> v[i].name;
  }
  return v;
}
```

Moreover, I noted in your code you create a vector of given size n, and pass it to the function for reading its content. So, if you really want to create a vector of a given size, and let the function just read the student data in that vector, you can just pass the `vector<student>` as an input/output parameter (using reference: `vector<student>&`), without specifying the additional `int n` parameter, as vectors know their own size (e.g. you can query it with `vector::size`):

```
void get_student_data(vector<student>& v)
{
  for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
  {
    cout << "Enter Name of " << (i+1) <<"th student\n";
    cin >> v[i].name;
  }
}
```